# Regex for matching this string

Tags: regex, python-3.x

With python ( regex module ), I am triying to substitute 'x' for each letter 'c' in those strings occurring in a text and:

1. delimited by 'a', at the left, and 'b' at the right, and
2. with no more 'a's and 'b's in them.

Example:

`cuacducucibcl` -> `cuaxduxuxibcl`

How can I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean with no more a's and b's in them?

Comment: @CommuSoft: a[^ab]*b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below regex and then replace the matched c's with `x` . For this , you need to install external `regex` module.

```
>>> import regex
>>> s = 'cuacducucibcl'
>>> regex.sub(r'((?:a|(?<!^)\G)[^abc\n]*)c', r'\1x', s)
'cuaxduxuxibcl'
```

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/rK5lU1/18)

Comment: @vks: It's from regex package. You need to install it from pypi. `re` doesn't support it. And @AvinashRaj please mention this in your answer.

Comment: yep, at the start of op's question `With python ( regex module )`

Comment: @nhahtdh any documentation to support this?m looking for it as well

Comment: @nhahtdh why it failed to support `\K` ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: You use that in your code. Even if you ask me why, I don't know how to answer... Does it work on your installation?

Comment: yep, the first regex won't work on python where the second one does. It because `\K`. Why Matt failed to implement `\K` on his module? sorry for asking you.

Comment: @nhahtdh didnt find `\K` over there.`\G` is there

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Remove the one with `\K` from your answer then.

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? Could you provide an example ?

Comment: >>> import regex as rx
>>> r = rx.compile ('(?:a|(?<!^)\G)[^abc\n]*\Kc(?=[^ab\n]*b)')
>>> r.sub ( 'x', 'cuacducucibcl')
'cuacducucibcl'

Comment: don't use \K. regex module don't have any support  for `\K`. See my answer.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. You are right. Thank you very much again. You are still a genius.

Answer (score 1):

With the standard `re` module in Python, you can use `a[^ab]+b` to match the string which starts and end with `a` and `b` and doesn't have any occurence of `a` or `b` in between, **then** supply a replacement function to take care of the replacement of `c`:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('a[^ab]+b', lambda m: m.group(0).replace('c', 'x'), 'cuacducucibcl')
'cuaxduxuxibcl'
```

Document of [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) for reference.